# How to properly get data from a database, manipulate it and serve to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to C# database stuff, I have a MVC project and I try to get, manipulate and serve data to a view from database after user is doing a search. I was able to get results from db but can't do anything with it. IQueryable is returning a 'Results View' List with all rows values from db, the problem is that I don't know how access that data, because 'Results View' is created at runtime, and I can't use SearchResult.ResultsView[0].City or something before runtime cause it's content will be null.

Please tell me how to properly get and manipulate data from a database, IQueryable returns a list at runtime but next ??? If you can explain a little or give some documentation to read I will be very thankful. Thanks!

I have a class:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
[Table("LInfo")]
public class LInfo
    {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int LId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int DistrictNo { get; set; }

    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ProcessedBy { get; set; }
    public int Pass { get; set; } //pass 0,1,2,3
    }
}
```

Which Image id is mapped to:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
[Table("Img")]
public class Img
    {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ImgId { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public bool Anonymous { get; set; }
    public bool Unreadable { get; set; }
    public bool MultipleFiles { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Pulled { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser UploadedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LetterInfo> Letters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this controller:

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
public class SearchController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Search
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SModel());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SModel model)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        int districtNo = Convert.ToInt32(model.DistrictNo);
        IQueryable SResult = db.LetterInfos.Where(l => l.DistrictNo == districtNo && l.State == model.State)
                         .Select(s => s);


        return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Example from Visual Studio:

http://prntscr.com/favjdg

Comment: don't forget to dispose of the open context, and execute the query by calling .ToList(), rather than enumerating the IQueryable directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be certain of your final goal, but it seems that currently you have:
a landing page with search; this form should post to the server and retrieve matching data as the searchresult model.

Your code was close, but I can suggest a few changes to get you started.  Originally....

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel model)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    int districtNo = Convert.ToInt32(model.DistrictNo);
    IQueryable SearchResult = db.LetterInfos.Where(l => l.DistrictNo == 
        districtNo && l.State == model.State)
        .Select(s => s);

    return View();
}
```

This is close, and nice use of Linq, but as previous answers have suggested, the IQueryable interface is not actually 
*executing* the query. To do so, I would add .ToList() and change the initial data type -- you can simplify this as:

```
var SearchResult = db.LetterInfos.Where(l => l.DistrictNo == 
        districtNo && l.State == model.State)
        .Select(s => s).ToList();
```

Finally, it seems that though you've gotten a **SearchResults** list from the DB, you are not passing this to your view as the model. You can choose to either return the same view with this new model, binding it to, for example a hidden results table with Razor, or you can choose to return a new view (you can see multiple overloads listed for View()).

Again, You can use this Index post method to pass back a *new* view and the model list by adding the newly populated object as the model to your view, or you may be able to reuse the original in some way:

```
return View("someView", SearchResult); 
   <or> 
return View(SearchResult);
```

Likewise, you should also specify the model in your other cshtml view (if you have not) as:

```
@model Namespace.SearchResults
     or 
@model List<Namespace.SearchResult>
     etc
```

Note: this assumes that you want the *same* view to be populated with the search results, and you have a public class inside of your solution that corresponds with SearchResult.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

An IQueryable represents a query, not a collection.  It has methods like .AsEnumerable() and .ToList() which will execute the query and return a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel model)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            int districtNo = Convert.ToInt32(model.DistrictNo);
            var SearchResult = db.LetterInfos.Where(l => l.DistrictNo == districtNo && l.State == model.State)
                         .ToList();


            return View(SearchResult);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to modify your view so it accept `IEnumerable<LetterInfo>` as model and properly display it

Comment: Hey, the thing is that SearchResult is null before runtime, so properties that I try to use in a View will be a simple syntax error so the project won't build. I need to somehow use in the view a class with defined properties and at runtime to copy values from SearchResult into those properties.. not sure about approach :)

Comment: can you post your view? looks like you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need a foreach to access your list of data

```
foreach(var i in SearchResult)
{
    //"i" will have access to your data
}
```